# Isomorphism between left and right cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H < G$ a subgroup. I know that there is a bijection between the left and right cosets of $H$. Under what conditions can I say that there is a *group isomorphism* between them?

Comment: What does isomorphism mean in this context?

Comment: Group isomorphism

Comment: The set of left cosets is not a group, in general.

Comment: You are right. I meant to say that $H$ is normal. I will edit my question

Comment: But if $H$ is normal then the set (or group if you prefer) of left cosets is the same as the set of right cosets.  $gH=Hg$.  So, of course, the two groups are isomorphic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$ is a group iff $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
In this case, the set of left cosets and the set of right cosets coincide, and define the same quotient group.